# How to escape JSON string for CSV parsing?

Tags: json, csv, encoding, escaping

A bit of an odd question perhaps.

I'm trying to Store a JSON string appropriately in a CSV column as a string. It works OK when generating the CSV file, however parsing the CSV file with the JSON in it is a problem.

I've tried `"{"prop": "Val"...}"`, `"{""prop"": ""Val""...}"`, `"{\"prop\": \"Val\"...}"`, `"{\""prop\"": \""Val\""...}"`

However none of them parse well at all.

Please help!

Comment: I've just put "{""prop"": ""Val"",""prop2"": ""Val2""}" and it works ok. Can you show us what is the result that you are obtaining and what is the result expected?

Comment: search for online csv encode/decode and it will make the job for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer here is to double quote the JSON string so this:

```
{ "a": 10 }
```

converts into this:

```
"{ ""a"": 10 }"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following replace logic to escape your JSON string:

```
`"${YOUR_JSON_STR.replace(/\"/g, '""')}"`
```